# constraining on classes of column in data frame in R

Tags: r, class, types, dataframe

So, I am trying to write a function with a dataframe as input to check whether the columns of the  dataframe only contains integer, character(not factor) and numeric vectors. In that case I want to return value `TRUE`. If it contains something else, I want to return `FALSE`.

for example :

```
df1 <- data.frame( a = 1:4, b = c("x","y", "z","w"), c = 8:11, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 2:5,  b = c("m", "n", "o", "p"),c = 11:14, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

In this case, the function should return `TRUE` with input `df1` since it has integer and character type columns. But for `df2`, I want to return `FALSE` since it contains factor column `b`.

Could someone help?

Comment: Try `f1 <- function(dat) !any(sapply(dat, is.factor)); f1(df1); f1(df2)`

Comment: Are you saying you want **all** the columns to be of either numeric or character?  And what about the other classes, like "Date"?

Comment: Yes, **all** the columns should be either numeric, character or integer.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for you reply. But your solution only checks whether it doesn't contain in factor column. But here we need to check for other types too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since integers are also numeric, you can use the condition

```
is.numeric(x) | is.character(x)
```

Here's a function:

```
numOrChar <- function(df) {
    f <- function(x) is.numeric(x) | is.character(x)
    all(vapply(df, f, logical(1L)))
}

numOrChar(df1)
# [1] TRUE
numOrChar(df2)
# [1] FALSE
```